# Android 8.1 connecting to a BLE peripheral calling connectGatt. Callback always says disconnected. Never connects

Tags: android, bluetooth-lowenergy, android-8.1-oreo

I am new to Android programming and trying to write an app that works with a BLE peripheral. I have an iOS app that I wrote which does the same thing and my iOS app already works the way I want it to.

I've written an activity that scans for a list of my peripherals. This seems to be working fine so far.

Then I select a peripheral and pass the BluetoothDevice object to a "device details" activity which is supposed to connect to the peripheral and then do some things with it.

In my device details activity, I grab a reference to the connect button and then add a click listener. The click listener creates an instance of MyBluetoothGattCallback and then uses it as a parameter to call connectGatt(). This call does return what looks like a valid BluetoothGatt object. MyBluetoothGattCallback is called, but it is only called once and the status is 133 and the state is 0. That appears to be  BluetoothProfile.STATE_DISCONNECTED. The callback is never called again. This happens every time I press the connect button.

I have already made sure that one and only one scan operation happens and that it is stopped from the main activity of the app. So scanning is not happening at this point.

My question is what should I be doing differently to get the connection to work?

```
public class DeviceDetails extends AppCompatActivity {

public BluetoothDevice mBluetoothDevice;
public BluetoothSocket mBluetoothSocket;
public BGXBluetoothGattCallback mGattCallback;
public BluetoothGatt mBluetoothGatt;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_device_details);
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    TextView titleTextView = findViewById(R.id.DeviceDetailsTitleTextView);

    mBluetoothDevice = (BluetoothDevice) getIntent().getExtras().getParcelable("BLUETOOTH_DEVICE");
    String sdeviceName = mBluetoothDevice.getName();
    if (null == sdeviceName) {
        sdeviceName = "No device name";
    }

    titleTextView.setText(sdeviceName);

    Button connectButton = findViewById(R.id.connectButton);
    connectButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Log.d("debug", "Connect button pressed");
            if (null == mGattCallback) {
                mGattCallback = new MyBluetoothGattCallback();
            }

            mBluetoothGatt = mBluetoothDevice.connectGatt(DeviceDetails.this, false, mGattCallback);

        }
    });
}
```

This is my BluetoothGattCallback subclass:

```
public class MyBluetoothGattCallback extends BluetoothGattCallback {
@Override
public void onConnectionStateChange(BluetoothGatt gatt, int status, int newState) {
    super.onConnectionStateChange(gatt,status,newState);

    Log.d("debug", "onConnectionStateChange status: " + status + " newState: "+newState);

    switch(newState) {
        case BluetoothProfile.STATE_CONNECTING:
            Log.d("debug", "connection state: CONNECTING.");
            break;
        case BluetoothProfile.STATE_CONNECTED:
            Log.d("debug", "connection state: CONNECTED.");
            break;
        case BluetoothProfile.STATE_DISCONNECTING:
            Log.d("debug", "connection state: DISCONNECTING.");
            break;
        case BluetoothProfile.STATE_DISCONNECTED:
            Log.d("debug", "connection state: DISCONNECTED.");
            break;
        default:
            Log.d("debug", "connection state: OTHER.");
            break;
    }
}

@Override
public void onServicesDiscovered(BluetoothGatt gatt, int status) {
    super.onServicesDiscovered(gatt, status);
    Log.d("debug", "onServicesDiscovered.");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out there was nothing wrong with this code that was causing the result seen. I cleared the bonding information from the embedded device, rebooted the phone and then it connected, discovered services, etc.